# Temperature change in Adiabatic stretching of liquid film

Tags: thermodynamics, maxwell-relations

The first law applied to a liquid film is $dU = dQ +2\sigma dA$ where $\sigma$ stands for surface tension.

Or $dQ = dU + (-2\sigma) dA \leftrightarrow dQ = dU + PdV$

Now suppose we wish to find what happens to temperature if I increase the area adiabatically. (Throughout I assume the stretching to be reversible.)

i.e. we need to know $\left(\frac{dT}{dA}\right)_S$

I propose two methods here to calculate this.

**Method 1** (quite straight-forward)

Clearly for adiabatic processes $dQ=0$ i.e. $dU = 2\sigma dA$. Here $dU=C_A dT$. So, we get $dT = \frac{2\sigma}{C_A} dA$

Or $\left(\frac{dT}{dV}\right)_S = \frac{2\sigma}{C_A}$

**Method 2** (uses Maxwell relations)

As we know following Maxwell relation,
$\left(\frac{dT}{dV}\right)_S = - \left(\frac{dP}{dS}\right)_V$

which in our case would correspond to 
$\left(\frac{dT}{dA}\right)_S = 2 \left(\frac{d\sigma}{dS}\right)_A = 2T \left(\frac{d\sigma}{dQ}\right)_A$.

Also $(dQ)_A = (dU)_A = C_A dT$

This would mean 
$\left(\frac{dT}{dA}\right)_S = \frac{2T}{C_A} \left(\frac{d\sigma}{dT}\right)_A$

My teacher says that it is the second method which is correct, but I can not figure out why first one is ***wrong*** since both can not certainly be right together.

Comment: In the first derivation are you not assuming that $\sigma$ is constant?

Comment: @Farcher I don't think so. But be my guest and explain it clearly. Note dQ, dU and 2\sigma dA are differential quantities.

Comment: It was an suggestion because if $dU = 2 \sigma dA$ then $U=2\sigma A$.  Differentiating with respect to $T$ gives you two terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error in method 1 was assuming the U = U(T) and not U = U(T,A).  But, you would have been much better off starting out directly with entropy S = S(T,A), so that $$dS=\frac{C_A}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial A}\right)_TdA$$Then from the Maxwell relationship, $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial A}\right)_T=-2\left(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial T}\right)_A$$
So,$$dS=\frac{C_A}{T}dT-2\left(\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial T}\right)_AdA$$

Answer (score 2):

In the **method 1**, you expressed increase of energy during adiabatic process as

$$
dU=C_A dT
$$

where $C_A$ is presumably capacity when the area $A$ is constant:
$$
C_A = \left(\frac{dU}{dT}\right)_A.
$$
But $C_A$ is not the right factor to use for adiabatic process, because in this process $A$ is not constant, but $S$ is. The energy increase formula is actually

$$
dU=C_S dT
$$
where 
$$
C_S = \left(\frac{dU}{dT}\right)_S.
$$

We then have the relation

$$
2\sigma dA = \left(\frac{dU}{dT}\right)_S dT
$$
But $C_S$ is not measurable, so we still cannot express sought quantity in terms of known things.

If we try to use Maxwell's relations on $C_S$, we find we can't, because the pair of variables $T,S$ is not sufficient to determine the thermodynamic state. Only pairs $(S,A), (T,A), (S, \sigma), (T,\sigma)$ qualify.

So the method 1 does not really work. The task is to express $dT/dA|S$ in terms of something known, and with the hint of the pair of variables $(S,A)$ in the low, one can try to use the Maxwell relation

$$
\frac{dT(S,A)}{dA} = 2\frac{d\sigma(S,A)}{dS}.
$$

that follows from the fundamental relation

$$
dU = TdS +2\sigma dA.
$$

Here $U,T,\sigma$ are all functions of $(S,A)$.

One then proceeds as in your **method 2**.